# Using boost::archive with boost::iostreams to compress data

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, compression

I want to write a serialize function for a class that can optionally compress the data.  I would like to use the compression facilities provided in boost::iostreams.  Does anyone know how to do this?

```
struct X
{
    X() {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & compression;
        if(compression == 0)
        {
            ar & data;
        }
        else if(compression == 1)
        {
            // use boost::iostream compression
            // facilities to serialize data
        }
    }

    int compression;
    std::vector<int> data;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can see to do that is compress the data first and then use ar.load_binary and ar.save_binary. To compress the data, you could use a filtering_stream with std::ostringstream as sink and an appropriate compression filter.

Any reason you don't want to push the compression down the stack (that is, build your archive over a compressing stream)?